# What is the safe temperature range for nylon sutures?

Tags: dentistry, heat, tooth-extraction, sutures

I got one of my teeth extracted. The dentist applied a suture using a nylon string. I've been advised to not eat hot food because the suture would melt.
Now I'm wondering what is the maximum safe temperature for food that I eat.

Comment: This obviously isn't all of it (since the dentist said it would melt) but part of this is also because if you have some form of wound that requires sutures in your mouth; eating hot food can also cause swelling and added pain.

Comment: The main reason for my question is that I don't know whether my "warm" definition is cool enough. I am eating completely cold meals as a result. Main problem is the cooling time.